# can I use hash.each even if i'm passing only a string key? Dictionary without definition

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hash, parameters, each

This is the error I'm getting. I need to pass a string key to a method that usually accepts string key and string symbol combo

```
Dictionary
  is empty when created`
  can add whole entries with keyword and definition
  add keywords (without definition) (FAILED - 1)

  Failures:

    1) Dictionary add keywords (without definition)
       **Failure/Error: @d.add('fish')
       NoMethodError:
         undefined method `each' for "fish":String
       # ./11_dictionary/dictionary.rb:9:in `add'**
       # ./11_dictionary/dictionary_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the following spec. the @d.add('fish') passes a string without definition.
require 'dictionary'

```
describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

 it 'is empty when created' do
    @d.entries.should == {}
  end

  it 'can add whole entries with keyword and definition' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end

  it 'add keywords (without definition)' do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => nil}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end
```

my code:

I think my definition.each is where it goes wrong. From what I understand each goes through the array or hash in this example but only has one value so it doesn't know how to loop through it? So I thought about setting a default nil value for meaning and word but it doesn't accept it and comes with different errors.

```
class Dictionary
  attr_accessor :keywords, :entries

  def initialize
    @entries = {}
  end

  def add(definition)
    definition.each do |word, meaning|   
    @entries[word] = meaning

    end
  end

  def keywords
     @entries.keys.sort
  end


  def include?(key)
    @entries.key?(key)
  end

  def find(query)
    @entries.select { |word, definition| word.scan(query).join == query}
  end

  def entries
     @entries
  end

end
```

Thanks for you help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `each` on a `String` in `@d.add('fish')`, which isn't allowed. You could just add the following line above `definition.each do |word, meaning|`:

```
definition = { definition => nil } unless definition.is_a? Hash
```

although this could have unexpected consequences if you are passing different kinds of objects to `add`.

Answer (score 0):

My code is rough..  This works too.

def add(hash)

if (hash.is_a? Hash)

```
  @d=hash
```

else

```
  @d = {hash => nil}
```

end